# Using timestamp in text format published parameter of FME?

Tags: fme-form, parameters, timestamp, file-path

I have an FME workspace (FME 2015.1) that creates an output file, let's say `result.xslx`. What I would like to do is to build up the output file name from various parameters, e.g. the project name and the creation date like `myprojectname_result_20161017.xlsx`.

Obviously, the `DestDataset_...` published parameters cannot be built in such way using the TextEditor like `$(project)_result_@timestamp(yyyymmmdd).xlsx`. Promising approach is to build up a text published parameter and use this as a source for the `DestDataset_...` published parameter.

Where the project name is no problem to achieve, I am not able to access the actual date like described in the above way in creating published parameters. So the problem can be reduced to the question:

In FME, how to automaticaly insert the actual date (timestamp) into a text format published parameter?

Comment: It may not be necessary to use a published parameter. The actual date that the workspace has run can be determined within the workspace itself. The following info would be a good place to start. [Including Dates into the Names of Output Files or Features](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1213/including-dates-into-the-names-of-output-files-or.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A TimeStamper will create an attribute with yyyymmdd. Next you can fanout on both filename and sheetname:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Fanouts are a great idea - probably the easiest way. However, you can also use parameters.

The [FME advanced training manual](https://www.gitbook.com/book/safe-software/fme-desktop-advanced-training-2016/details) has a section (Shared Parameters) that shows how to embed one parameter inside another, like so:

```
Output File: $(OutputFolder)\$(Username).txt
```

To get the date you would use a Scripted Parameter. That can be a TCL or Python script that carries out an action and returns a value.

For example, here's a code snippet that returns a path depending on which platform you are running on:

```
if {[string match 'C:*' $FME_MacroValues(FME_HOME)]} {
    set realname 'C:\Output\'+$FME_MacroValues(UserFileName)
} else {
    set realname '/Output/'++$FME_MacroValues(UserFileName)
}

return realname
```

You would just need to use some sort of Python/TCL function to capture the current date and time. I don't know what it would be off hand, but I'm sure there is such a function.

That way you can build up quite a complex output path, perhaps using a combination of embedded parameters and scripted parameters - plus any other sort of parameter you like. For example:

```
$(ScriptedPlatformPath)\$(ProjectParameter)\$(ScriptedTimestamp).xlxs
```